# How would I get numbers from the beginning of a line of text, split them and print them out

Tags: python, file, text

Here is my dilemma: I'm  writing an application in Python that will allow me to search a flat file (KJV bible.txt) for particular strings, and return the line number, book, and string searched for. However, I would also like to return the chapter and verse in which the string was found. That calls for me going to the beginning of the line and getting the chapter and verse number. I'm a Python neophyte, and am currently still reading through the Python tutorial by Guido van Rossum. This is something I'm trying to accomplish for a bible study group; something portable that can ran in the cmd module almost anywhere. I appreciate any help ... Thanks. Below is an excerpt from an example of a Bible chapter:

```
 Daniel


 1:1 In the third year of the reign of Jehoiakim king of Judah came
 Nebuchadnezzar king of Babylon unto Jerusalem, and besieged it.
```

Say I searched for 'Jehoiakim' and one of the search results was the first line above. I would like to go to the numbers that precede this line (in this case 1:1) and get the chapter (1) and verse (1) and print them to the screen.

```
 1:2 And the Lord gave Jehoiakim king of Judah into his hand, with part
 of the vessels of the house of God: which he carried into the land of
 Shinar to the house of his god; and he brought the vessels into the
 treasure house of his god.
```

Code:

```
 import os
 import sys
 import re

 word_search = raw_input(r'Enter a word to search: ')
 book = open("KJV.txt", "r")
 first_lines = {36: 'Genesis', 4812: 'Exodus', 8867: 'Leviticus', 11749: 'Numbers', 15718: 'Deuteronomy',
           18909: 'Joshua', 21070: 'Judges', 23340: 'Ruth', 23651: 'I Samuel', 26641: 'II Samuel',
           29094: 'I Kings', 31990: 'II Kings', 34706: 'I Chronicles', 37378: 'II Chronicles',
           40502: 'Ezra', 41418: 'Nehemiah', 42710: 'Esther', 43352: 'Job', 45937: 'Psalms', 53537: 'Proverbs',
           56015: 'Ecclesiastes', 56711: 'The Song of Solomon', 57076: 'Isaih', 61550: 'Jeremiah',
           66480: 'Lamentations', 66961: 'Ezekiel', 71548: 'Daniel' }


 for ln, line in enumerate(book):
     if word_search in line:
         first_line = max(l for l in first_lines if l < ln)
         bibook = first_lines[first_line]

         template = "\nLine: {0}\nString: {1}\nBook:\n"
         output = template.format(ln, line, bibook)
         print output
```

Comment: If you want your application to be portable then you probably want to make an executable out of your program, so that python does not have to be installed to run it. Check out this [link](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) for a simple way to accomplish this.

Comment: @SC Ghost - Thanks ... yeah, currently I use py2exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html): `r'(\d+)\.(\d+)'`

After finding a match (`match = re.match(r'(\d+)\.(\d+)', line)`), you can find the chapter in group 1 (`chapter = match.group(1)`) and the verse in group 2.

Use this code:

```
 for ln, line in enumerate(book):
      match = match = re.match(r'(\d+)\.(\d+)', line)
      if match:
           chapter, verse = match.group(1), match.group(2)

      if word_search in line:
           ...
           print 'Book %s %s:%s ...%s...' % (book, chapter, verse, line)
```

Comment: Before `if word_search`. In this case, you need to check if `match is not None` and remember the values in global variables, so they get updated as you read the text.

Comment: I thought I understood, but can you tell me where I went wrong in my code (edited)?

Comment: I got a traceback error that I'm trying to debug (added to code above).

Comment: with this re: re.match(r'(\d+)', line) and just chapter = match.group(1) I get the chapter. But if I add the second (.\d+) and verse = match.group(2) I continuously get a traceback error?

Answer (score 5):

Do a single split on whitespace, then split on `:`.

```
passage, text = line.split(None, 1)
chapter, verse = passage.split(':')
```

Comment: I added code ... how would, after my search results, go back to look for the numbers?

Comment: This is the traceback error that I'm getting                                                                           Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\SQA_log\biblebooks.py", line 26, in <module>
    chapter, verse = passage.split(':')
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: You probably have whitespace at the beginning of the line then. `... = line.lstrip().split(None, 1)`